# Inconsistent TypeScript behavior

Tags: typescript

Can somebody explain me this case, I have some types and definitions:

```
    type Registro = {
        id: number;
        registro: string;
        nombre: string;
    };

    const registros: Registro[] = [
        {
            id: 0,
            registro: '4324',
            nombre: 'Ben'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            registro: '232',
            nombre: 'Jill'
        }
    ];
```

If I use a literal string 'id', TS compiles fine

```
    const a = registros[0]['id']; //OK
```

If I use a constant straight from a literal, TS also compiles fine

```
    const key1 = 'id';
    const c = registros[0][key1]; //OK
```

If I use a variable as a key even though it says its a :string , it will give an error

```
    let key2 = 'id';
    const d = registros[0][key2];
    //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Registro'.
    //No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Registro'.ts(7053)
```

If I use a constant as a key coming from a variable. and also it says its a :string , it will also error

```
    let key3 = 'id';
    const key4 = key3;
    const e = registros[0][key4];
    //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Registro'.
    //No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Registro'.
```

What is the problem?

[Typescript REPL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASALgngDgpgBAJRgcwJYGcwCcD2cC8cA3qCKgCYBccAdgK4C2ARjFgNylYobY7WZZUNZBxAgaOZl37YhI0AF8OoAMY4amOFzQCc6akh28A2gF0CcY6RJiyVOAAYANKRDaeuagHIALAGYAJh8vF1sJKRhvACEYGi9SBVCQGzEKagBGJLduXW8AwJDXcKZpOC8AKVQAGyr4sQVQU2UQNQ0wOABDC3dddGMHU2MvCi8muAB6cYB5AGlgVXVNAGsYCHSLYfIvUVbNFW6c3j6B4xW1scnZ+ZAqmHazgI2RncX28gOjXGPBh6bQSYAorcGLF2qgGFAqqgVKgwFUIHAABYddCdGhlDo0CBeOCQWBwFgqDp0dDwGAADygXHQ6FQ6jgOAAZrjoPAvAI5DiiXF2iw4CSYO8wHghOQKSz8V5DB4cF4AHT-cYAORFNDF5LgtOQNA6YDoXDgAHdYYjOnAoB0sB0QWBWAzmXi2RzhDjDSi4IycHQ1Qz0Y6ytLdPKwOgABQAdgcAFY-ABKa63e6rPxPLYvNpwM4+CxnPzpzTwQg9I79H6rHx-OBVibjIEwEE0MEQqEwuEI5GozEYrE4-2E4mkuAUqkwGl09FMiVO2QuuDcry8+ACoWq9VTgOHXDy4DVmsquCi8VanV6g3GsCmroWq02u2T-3smfIV3uz3e970h+B3jyoA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot be sure that the key declared as `let` will always be equal to one of the keys, so it considers this variable as a general `string`. You may fix it by setting the type of the key

```
type keys = 'id' | 'registro' | 'nombre'

let key2: keys = 'id';
const d = registros[0][key2];
```

Now the compiler will do its best to warn you if `key2` is not a valid key.

Comment: Thanks, your answere walked me to a more elegant solution:  type keys = keyof Registro;

Answer (score 2):

In short:
When you use const to declare a string variable, the compiler will set the type to be the string itself. When you use let\var, the compiler will set it as `string`, which is not allowed to be used as an index.

Well, I didn't know the answer by myself, and I found this question very interesting. So after digging a little bit, I found the answer:

> When you declare a variable via var or let, you are telling the compiler that there is the chance that this variable will change its contents. In contrast, using const to declare a variable will inform TypeScript that this object will never change.
> The process of going from an infinite number of potential cases (there is an infinite number of possible string values) to a smaller, finite number of potential case (in helloWorld’s case: 1) is called narrowing.

```
// We're making a guarantee that this variable
// helloWorld will never change, by using const.
 
// So, TypeScript sets the type to be "Hello World", not string
const helloWorld = "Hello World";
 
// On the other hand, a let can change, and so the compiler declares it a string
let hiWorld = "Hi World";
```

The source: [Literal Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `const` it works because the type, in your examples, will be the value itself. In `const key1 = 'id';`, type of key1 is 'id'.

If you assign the const like `const key1: string = 'id';` it won't work, as key1 now is type of string.